# How does `git pull --rebase` correctly pull amended commits?

Tags: git, git-pull

I have a setup where I code on my `local` machine and pull it from my `dev` box to test it.
Say I create a commit `A` on branch `foo` on `local`, and create a branch `foo` on dev box which has upstream set as `local/foo`. If I do a `git pull` from branch `foo` on dev box, branch tree of `dev/foo` becomes same as `local/foo`.

But if I now amend the commit `A` in `local/foo`, `git pull` from branch `foo` on dev box gives a merge conflict. Whereas `git pull --rebase` works correctly and does not dupicate commit `A` twice on `dev/foo`.

`git help pull` says that:

```
       -r, --rebase[=false|true|merges|preserve|interactive]
           When true, rebase the current branch on top of the upstream branch after 
fetching. If there is a remote-tracking branch corresponding to the upstream branch 
and the upstream branch was rebased since last fetched, the rebase uses that 
information to avoid rebasing non-local changes.
```

I get that the last line is being applied in the above scenario, but I don't understand what the pre-conditions are or how its working?

An explanation would be very helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is because of the difference of merging and rebasing.

"Regular" `git pull` first fetches the changes and then
merges them into the local state, while `git pull --rebase`
fetches the changes and then rebases the local state on top
of the remote's.

Merging considers only the two states of the project—the "ours"
and "thiers" side of the merge, plus, when possible,
the so-called "merge-base" of them—the last common commit
these lines of development shared.

Rebasing, on the contrary, first resets the "ours" side to
point to the same commit the "theirs" side has at its tip
and then applies each "ours" commit "theirs" does not have
*individually—as textual patches,* one-by-one.

This may have a greater chance of not producing conflicts
as the local changes are re-applied onto the remote's updated
state *incrementally.*

Comment: In general, I'd recommend to follow the advice of complerely forgetting about `git pull` and always use `git fetch` + look around + merge or rebase, as detailed in https://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/ — pulling has too much magic built-in, and it's sadly usually taught first which leads to the devs cargo-culting it without really understanding what happens when it runs.

Comment: The observed behaviour is that local changes(from the POV of dev box) are not applied at all. This happens in a special scenario which I am not able to grasp. I am familiar with their usages and best practices, this was more of a curiosity.

Comment: Correct and upvoted, but I'd add two things: merge *always* has a merge base, even if it has to use the empty tree; and rebase has a peculiar feature (misfeature?) called `--fork-point` in modern Git, which sometimes omits commits, and when it does that's often correct, but occasionally wrong and very confusing. The fork-point code exists only in `git pull --rebase` in some early versions of Git. In modern Git, `git rebase` itself does the fork-point handling.

Comment: @torek, do you mean Git always uses a 3-way merge even when merging unrelated histories?

Comment: @Nishant, you may try to state a separate question trying to describe your problem (but since solving this problem might well require several "ping-pongs" to refine the context you might be better off posting to [the developers' mailing list](https://gist.github.com/tfnico/4441562#writing-an-email-to-the-developers-list) instead).

Comment: @kostix: yes: the merge base for unrelated histories is the empty tree. (Internal shortcut hack: Git only needs a tree, not an actual commit, once it's picked a commit.) As a result any files with the same name on either side produce an add/add conflict.